# Automating the import data process of an usually formatted CSV file into SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net, csv

I'm working on a system that needs to import data from CSV files into SQL server. The CSV file has two different sets of data. Each set of data has its own table in the database. (Please see image attached to understand how the CSV looks like)

[image: csv file]

To use the Import/Export feature I have to copy paste both sets into two different CSV files and then import them one at a time so the mapping works correctly.

The system will be dealing with 1000s of CSV files on a daily basis. So the process needs to be automated.  I guessing I need to write some .net script to process every CSV file that will take data and dump it into the data base.  Am I correct? Any other suggestions?

Comment: IF you have SQL Server, don't you have SSIS?

Comment: I do have SSIS. But I have 1000s of CSV files that need to be modified before I can use SSIS. If I try SSIS directly on the above CSV it does not recognize the right fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our approach was creating a service that integrated with our main application, which would read queue of CSV and XLS files sent by users, parse them and stored them into data tables in DBMS (Oracle or SQL Server)
The advantage of this approach is that your service can do some other things and send messages back to your application.

Users can do it through familiar interface (your app) vs learning new tools. Basically, there is full integration with the application, however the actual processing is done on a dedicated server.

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. But I'm not sure how to accomplish this. I could do a VBScript to modify and create new CSVs and then use SSIS-BI to import that data into SQL Server.

Comment: Once file is in queue, the winservice runs an application that knows what to do with the file using Office Interop. I mean, in our case there is no script or any tools - it is all in c# code. You can read CSV and XLS just like DB tables and then do any manipulations and parsing of the data before storing it in the main DB.

Comment: So you're suggesting to write such an application in C# or vb.net, correct?  And not using SSIS-BI?

Comment: I know only little about your business and requirements. But from stand point of integration and ability to control processes, writing custom code always works better. Third party tools are good too. For example, if I am a doctor and I want to submit patient data using Excel to some server - if I use an application with integrated code,  the application already knows, who submitted the data, how to parse it and where to put it. But if I ftp file to your server, you need to parse this file to know who is this file from, you need to know which job to run, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Talend](http://www.talend.com/products/data-integration) is also a great tool especially for this kind of stuff. You can design your import jobs from and to any data source (including from CSV to Excel).

If the amount of data is rather big for each CSV file, I would write some jobs which leverage the bulk insert feature of the SqlClient. This makes data insertion a lot faster...

Talend supports bulk inserts, so this should be pretty easy to create...

We have 100s of Talend Jobs which not only copy data but also does a lot of transformations etc... It is a pretty solid thing and it is free...

Comment: So are you saying that Talend will provide the ability to process 100s of CSV files, convert selected fields from that CSV, put it in a separate file and then also insert data from the new file into SQL server?

Comment: yes, easily! That's what this tool is really good at. Also you can design those "tasks" and run them wherever you want, it actually compiles into a jar file (Talend generates Java code in the background).

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach would be:

1. Create a Job (e.g. Windows Service) that run every day, checks the folder where you receive the files and splits each csv file in 2 csv files (type_1 and type_2)
2. Create a Job in SQL Server that run after the first job and that uses [BULK INSERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)
   to import each type of file into its corresponding table.